# Best way and problems when using ajax tabs with an MVC PHP project

Tags: php, ajax, model-view-controller

I'm building an IMDB.com like website using PHP/jQuery and a MVC approach (no OOP).

I have an index.php base controller to 'rule them all' :), a controllers folder with all the controllers, a models folder and a view folder.

In some pages of the website I have tabbed navigation, when the visitor clicks on one of those tabs to get more information, jQuery gets that data using the $.post or $.get method and shows it on the tab container, obviously without refreshing the page.

The problem is that those pages loaded by ajax are also generated using controllers, models, and views, and the things are getting a bit complicated for someone like me ( = 'no experience'). To dynamically get the data I some times need to include a model twice, include an include in an include in an include, send information multiple times, connect with the database again, and all sort of things like that and I'm sure there is a better and prettier way to do this.

I'm searching for the best approach and common methods for this. I have no experience working with a big project like this. This is a personal project so I have full control and every answer is welcome.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the X-Requested-With header that most js frameworks send to see if the request is coming via ajax. Then you can only output certain data and not the "entire page".

Not sure why you need multiple includes like you say, maybe you need to rework your logic.

Post some code and we can be of better help.

Answer (score 0):

"To dynamically get the data I some times need to include a model twice, include an include in an include in an include, send information multiple times, connect with the database again, and all sort of things like that and I'm sure there is a better and prettier way to do this."

I think you need a better 'design' for you MVC application. Multiple includes - i am guessing in the different layers of the MVC framework might be indicators that your design needs more attention.

I'll try and be short:

Other frameworks i.e. handle requests via XMLHTTPRequest by AMONG others, disabling or enabling the VIEW or LAYOUT explicitly - check Zend Framework - (e.g. you need to send a JSON encoded string as a response). **These requests are handled just as any other request.**

I would suggest you have a look at other popular frameworks. Check the application design and layout, and pay attention on the Routing and Dispatching of Actions. I suggest you follow this path since as you say you lack experience.

good luck with your project.